# Given the subspace $ x_1 +\cdots+ x_n =C$ and a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, how would you find the projection of this vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the equation and subspace $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n =C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How would you find the projection of this vector $v$ on the subspace $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n =C$?

Comment: Subtract the normal until it lands on the hyperplane.

Comment: @copper.hat Hmm, okay. Could you expand on that or point me to any resources? Would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to do some work yourself.

Comment: Your subspace has $n+1$ variables. Did you mean to start with $x_1?$ Also, this doesn’t define a vector subspace, since it isn’t closed under addition. It defines a hyper plane, which is not something we normally call a “subspace.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh yeah, good catch. Supposed to start with $x_1$. It doesn't define a vector space? I was thinking of e.g. x + y + z = C which defines plane. So shouldn't the same apply to the equation above?

Comment: A plane is not a vector subspace, unless it contains the $0$ vector.

Comment: Draw a little picture for the $n=2$ case (set $C=1$ to be definite) and consider the first comment again.

Comment: A plane is an "affine subspace", which is not a "subspace" in the sense of linear algebra unless, as Thomas mentioned, it contains the zero vector.

Comment: Hint: a perpendicular vector,$u,$ to your hyper plane is hidden in your formula for the hyper plane. Then compute real $\lambda$ so that $v+\lambda u$ so that it is in your hyperplane.

Comment: Was searching on this just now, is it correct that the normal is $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$? Or am I totally on the wrong track?

If that's the case, when you then subtract the normal vector from the vector we want to project, do you then get the correct projection?

Comment: Did you mean the orthogonal projection?

Comment: @robjohn Yup, I mean the orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the normal to the plane is $n=(1,...,1)^T$. The plane is defined by the set of points $p$ satisfying $n^T p = C$.

Compute $t$ such that $v+tn$ lies in the plane, that is
$n^T (v+tn) = C$, or $t= {C-n^Tv \over \|n\|^2}$.
Let $p = v+tn$.

Suppose $p'$ is any other point in the plane, then
$\|v-p'\|^2 = \|v-p\|^2 + \|p-p'\|^2$ since $n^T (p-p') = 0$.

Hence $p$ is the closest point on the plane to $v$.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. Say we have the plane $x +y + z = 3$. Then the normal is $(1, 1, 1)^T$. We then calculate $t = \frac{9}{3}$. Plugging in $t = 3$ into the equation does not give the correct result and I can't figure out why. I do see that the solution is $t = -2$, which gets us the the correct answer when plugged in.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Been tackling this all day, lmk if you know what I'm doing wrong if you could provide an example. Otherwise, have a good day/night.

Comment: What do you mean setting $t$ as above does not give the right result? What point are you trying to project?

Comment: Eh, I messed up, the $t$ should have a minus sign.

Comment: Np. Was trying to project $v = (2, 3, 4)$.

Comment: My formula for $t$ was missing a $C$, see above. For your numbers I get $t=-2$ and the projection is $(0,1,2)^T$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rewrite this subspace into the form $\lbrace Ax+y: x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rbrace$ for appropriate matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n-1)}$ and vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. You do this by observing that all of the subspaces elements are of the form
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   -x_2-x_3-\dots -x_n + c \\
   x_2 \\
   x_3 \\
   \vdots \\
   x_n
   \end{pmatrix} = 
   x_2\begin{pmatrix}
   -1 \\
   1\\
   0 \\
   \vdots\\
   \\0
   \end{pmatrix} + x_3
   \begin{pmatrix}
   -1 \\
   0\\
   1 \\
   \vdots\\
   \\0
   \end{pmatrix} + \dots + x_n
   \begin{pmatrix}
   -1 \\
   0\\
   0 \\
   \vdots\\
   \\1
   \end{pmatrix}
   +
   \begin{pmatrix}
   c \\
   0\\
   0 \\
   \vdots\\
   \\0
   \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
   I am sure that you can see the pattern.
2. The projection is an optimization problem
   $$
   \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\lVert v-Ax-y \rVert^2_2.
   $$
   You can check the optimality conditions but the solution is
   $$
   x=\left(A^\top A\right)^{-1} (A^\top v  - A^\top b).
   $$
3. The vector $x=(x_2, ..., x_n)$ gives you the values for every coefficient but $x_1$. That you can find out by substituting those into the equation
   $$
   x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = C.
   $$

Yes, you can just check at which point the perpendicular vector $(1, 1, \dots, 1)$ enters the plane. But I chose the above reasoning because it can also be applied when the perpendicular vector is not known.